# Firefox addon for showing color hex and border dimensions

Tags: colors, firefox-extensions

Is there an addon where I can click on an element and it will tell me the color hex and the dimensions of the border? Simply put, I have an image with a border that's a certain color, and I need the info to manipulate it to another image.

Comment: Does Firebug do this when you right click and `Inspect Element`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the firefox plugin called [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).  Great web development helper.  Will let you see & edit the CSS on any page.  I think this will be exactly what you were looking for ;)

Comment: +1 for Firebug. Colorzilla is handy too https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colorzilla/

Answer (score 2):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox is a great tool for inspecting web pages.  You will be able to inspect all of the css associated with any element.  You can even change the values if needed.  Firebug is an essential tool for any web development.  Google's Chrome has similar developer tools built-in (also essential).

Answer (score 0):

The simple application "[La Boîte à Couleur](http://pourpre.com/colorbox/indexen.php)" (understand "color box") allow you to get/know all informations about colors that you want (displayed on the screen or not).